# How to mock a method that returns a list of interfaces

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, repository-pattern

This is my repository method:

```
    public async Task<IList<IVehicleMake>> GetAllMakes()
    {
        var makes = Context.VehicleMakes.AsQueryable();

        return new List<IVehicleMake>(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<VehicleMake>>(await makes.ToListAsync()));
    }
```

I know how to mock the method that returns a concrete type, but as you can see, this method returns a list of Interfaces "IVehicleMake".

Is it possible to mock this kind of method and how?

Comment: shouldn't be enough with Assert.IsType<IList<IVehicleMake>>(result); ?

Comment: Elaborate. Why would it be any different to test an list of `IVehicleMake`? You could check properties and method of an interface, as needed, in the same way you would for any concrete type. Is there some sort of equality comparison that concerns you?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't express myself correctly. I would like to know how to mock this repository method so I can test my Service method that depends on this repository method?

Comment: Consider adopting a _canonical data model_.  Converting between types all the time just leads to potential data fidelity loss; increased maintenance; wasted CPU; poor performance

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a mocking framework such as [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4). It is not so different than mocking a simple interface.

Here is a sample code using MS Test and Moq

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    public class Vehicle{}
    public interface IVehicleMake
    {
        Vehicle Make();
    }
    public interface IVehicleMakeRepository
    {
        Task<IList<IVehicleMake>> GetAllMakes();
    }

    public class MyService
    {
        private readonly IVehicleMakeRepository vehicleMakeRepository;

        public MyService(IVehicleMakeRepository vehicleMakeRepository)
        {
            this.vehicleMakeRepository = vehicleMakeRepository;
        }

        public async Task DoSomething()
        {
            var makes = await vehicleMakeRepository.GetAllMakes();
            foreach (var make in makes)
            {
                var vehicule = make.Make();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyServiceTest
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class DoSomething
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public async Task Should_CallAllMakersOnce()
            {
                //Arrange
                var mockedMakers = new[] { new Mock<IVehicleMake>(), new Mock<IVehicleMake>(), };
                foreach (var mockedMaker in mockedMakers)
                {
                    mockedMaker.Setup(m => m.Make()).Returns(new Vehicle()).Verifiable();
                }
                var mockedRepository = new Mock<IVehicleMakeRepository>();
                mockedRepository
                    .Setup(m => m.GetAllMakes())
                    .ReturnsAsync(mockedMakers.Select(mm => mm.Object).ToList())
                    .Verifiable();
                var service = new MyService(mockedRepository.Object);
                //Act
                await service.DoSomething();
                //Assert
                mockedRepository.Verify(m => m.GetAllMakes(), Times.Once);
                foreach (var mockedMaker in mockedMakers)
                {
                    mockedMaker.Verify(m => m.Make(), Times.Once);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```